# Beamer overlays out of sync in slides and notes

Tags: beamer, overlays, notes

I am trying to use overlay specifications simultaneously in my slides and my notes. I am wondering why the following straight-forward example is not working, and what my alternatives are. As as you can see below, the first item, which should appear together with the first note, already comes with the second note, while the second and third item come with the third note.

I know that I can work around the issue by explicitly specifying something like `\node<1>[item] first note ...`, but that less practical and a lot less flexible than being able to use an `itemize` structure, or any other structure for that matter, in the notes slide. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> first item
        \item <2-> second item
        \item <3-> third item
\end{itemize}

\note{
\begin{itemize}
        \item <1> first note
        \item <2> second note
        \item <3> third note
\end{itemize}
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seems that combining the note page and the normal slide on one page somehow offsets the slideinframe-counter for the note page. A hacky workaround:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\trickdown}{%
        \advance\beamer@slideinframe by-1%
     }%   
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-3>{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> first item
        \item <2-> second item
        \item <3-> third item
\end{itemize}

\note{
\trickdown
\begin{enumerate}
   \item <1> first note
   \item <2> second note
   \item <3> third note
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you get a useless fourth page?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, therefore the `\begin{frame}<1-3>{Frame}` hack :)

Comment: Not bad at all, and usually I like hacky. The `\trickdown` idea is nice. But it all depends on having to set the overlay specifications explicitly for the frame: It breaks for no spec or `<1>` - no notes at all in both cases - and requires the right number to prevent the duplicated last note (`<1-3>`). To me, this is particularly an issue, because I often don't write my presentations in .tex directly, but in something that gets translated to .tex. And these makros don't handle those extra specifications well... But still, thanks, this is at least as solution for some cases!

Comment: @th4ckl Can you show an example for "It breaks for no spec or <1> - no notes at all in both cases". I just tried with a frame without any overlays and don't see a problem.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I did also removed the overlays from the items. So, it only becomes an issue, if there is no overlay spec in the frame, which makes it much less of a problem, yet prevents me from just using `\trickdown` with every note block.

Comment: I have seen several questions on this issue, and this is the answer that I prefer!
In 2022 this is not working anymore, but if you put the \trickdown soon *before* the \note{, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

*Inside* a frame, you may use `\note` with *overlay specifications* (p. 199, beamer manual, v3.36).

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> first item
          \note[item]<1>{first note}
        \item <2-> second item
          \note[item]<2>{second note}
        \item <3-> third item
          \note[item]<3>{third note}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, as I tried to say above, I am aware of this approch. But it is kind of inflexible. For example, if I use overlays in a `tikz` environment, I need to make the notes in a separate environment... Also `\note[item]`, as far as I can see, does not allow you to have multiple levels of itemization in your notes...

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to replicate the MWE of the answer by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers, but it doesn't work well.
Maybe newer versions of beamer work differently? (the answer is from 2016)

I have fixed it by moving `\trickdown` directly before `\note{}`:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand{\trickdown}{%
        \advance\beamer@slideinframe by-1%
     }%   
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-3>{Frame}
\begin{itemize}
        \item <1-> first item
        \item <2-> second item
        \item <3-> third item
\end{itemize}

\trickdown
\note{
\begin{enumerate}
   \item <1> first note
   \item <2> second note
   \item <3> third note
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If this is only a small change, a comment to the other answer would be enough and maybe an edit will be made to that answer.

Comment: Ok, let's wait a little, and if @samcarter_is_at_topan edits that answer, I will remove this one. The point is that that answer as it is now does not work anymore... :)