# Additional page with overlays in notes

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am trying to use overlays inside the notes of my presentation. This is needed to be able to explain a `tikzpicture` with overlays step by step. My current approach seems to add an additional page when the notes contain an overlay.

Consider the following MWE which uses a simple list instead of a `tikzpicture` on the slide itself:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Test
        \item<2-> Another test
    \end{itemize}

\note{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Test
        \item<2-> Another test
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of manually creating the overlays on the note page, let beamer do it for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1-> Test
        \item<2-> Another test
    \end{itemize}

\note[item]<1>{Test}
\note[item]<2>{Another test}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How would I add an additional nesting level into the notes with your approach?

Comment: @epR8GaYuh Nested notes are indeed complicated with this approach. As am alternative you could try this trick: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333896/36296

Comment: Ok, seems like adding something like `<1-4>` after `\begin{frame}` reduces the number of slides as expected.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh That sounds like cheating :)

Comment: Well I would also rather not hardcode the number of slides but at least it works. Why is that extra page created!? I presume this is a bug in beamer, right? The documentation is not very extensive on notes.