# How to use \note[itemize] for frames with overlays

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays, notes

I'd like to have notes on each slide of a frame I use overlay options like itemize[<+->] or \alert<2>. The following codes make the notes appear in the end. Using \note{itemize} inside the frame results in an error. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} %\note[itemize] {\item first note for the whole frame \item second note for the whole frame} %%% uncomment for reproducing error
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item first item
\item second item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}\note[itemize] {\item first note for the whole frame \item second note for the whole frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: See also (the possible duplicate?): [Beamer overlays out of sync in slides and notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/333890/134144)

Answer (score 1):

For the use within frames, you can use `\note[item]{}` like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item first item
\item second item
\end{itemize}
\note<1>[item]{first note for the whole frame}
\note<2>[item]{second note for the whole frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```